# Make a link redirect to the same page

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I've created a page with an article. On top of that there's a title. If people try to click this title I want them to be redirected to the same page.
Like this: https://gyazo.com/74350b4fe91c670c4101449ee1c928a4 If I click on the article it just refreshes the page.

I can't do this manually for every article because I'm using a script. 
The code I've written looks like this:

```html
echo '<a href="/"> <h1 class="entry-title">'.$row['postTitle'].'</h1></a>';
```

As you can see I wrote

```html
<a href="/">
```

and that's will not redirect me / refresh the page i'm viewing.

This is how it looks for me: https://gyazo.com/8a15ae274d8a7240b07100395460568d
as you can see it does not redirect me to the same page when i click the title.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is your HTML so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your custom PHP blog post template be able to display a title link that points back to the page, one way is to make use of your `$row[...`. variable.

Provided that,

- your URLS will look like your screenshots, such as `http://localhost/viewpost.php?id=8` when running locally and for example `http://www.yourwebsite.com/viewpost.php?id=8` when online
- you know how to refer to the post's id that is used in  the `...viewpost.php?id=8`, for example `$row['postID']`
- you don't yet have any variable or means to refer to your current domain `http://localhost` when local or `http://www.yourwebsite.com` when online

Then, I recommend a two-part approach:

Somewhere at the top of your code, or perhaps in an include you might use for such code-reuse purposes, define for example `$host`:

```php
$host='http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

Then, for your actual title link::

```php
echo '<a href="' . $host . '/viewpost.php?id=' . $row['postID'] . '"> <h1 class="entry-title">' . $row['postTitle'] . '</h1></a>';
```

### Explanation

- Separated HTML from the concatenation dots `.` with spaces, to be easier to read, as well as to support any helper programs such as `fmt` that you might use for wrapping long lines, so they have spaces to use for wrapping lines.
- Uses PHP's predefined [`$_SERVER`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable's `SERVER_NAME` , which, combined with the `http://`, the `$host` will be `http://localhost` when local and `http://www.yourwebsite.com` when online.
- Define `$host` as a variable once at the top of the page, because it is clearer that way and likely you will have a use for it elsewhere on the page, so this helps avoid having to repeat yourself writing `'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` everywhere else you may need to start forming the absolute URL
- `$host` is then combined with the pattern for the rest of the URL, to assemble the [absolute URL](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-an-absolute-url.htm)
- Absolute URL is helpful so that if a user saves your article to their computer, then later clicks the title link on their locally saved article, the user can still correctly reach the original online page
- As the article author, setting a link this way also means it can serve as a [permalink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permalink), which helps with search engine optimization (SEO)

Comment: Hello. I'm not writing every article in HTML directly. That's why I can't to this manually.

Comment: Are you using WordPress, or your own custom blog system built completely by yourself?

Comment: A blog system build completly by myself

Comment: Great, I've updated instructions, be sure to check whether your post id can be referenced by `$row['id']` or if not then what it should be, otherwise it should work.

Comment: It can not be referenced by $row['id']. I'm getting these errors: https://gyazo.com/0c96fd21e992480d26a974c07c9aed2b. Now when i click on the title it's http://localhost/viewpost.php?id=.

Comment: It's the id that is the problem. It has to know which id we currently are on and then problem is solved. Do you know how to fix? Thank you sir.

Comment: Nevermind i fixed it using echo '<h1><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>';

Comment: No problem, well, to get some more clues to fix this, do you remember how you knew to refer to page's title with `$row['postTitle']`? Was there some database table you were looking at, that might give clues on what the id field is named? for example `$row['postId']`?

Comment: Great! Thanks for accepting. May all your problems be small ones like that. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Please use **#** in href attribute! that will redirect you on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I used

```html
echo '<h1><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>';
```

Thank you everyone.